# Mensagens de erro em português do SQLServer - (LocalDB)\v11.0

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, connectionstring

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação com o *Entity Framework 6* utilizando a abordagem *Code-First*.

Quero configurar o SQLServer (LocalDB)\v11.0 para apresentar as mensagens de erro em português sem utilizar o **SQL Server Management Studio**.

Pela pesquisa que fiz, uma das possibilidades, seria utilizar o atributo `Current Language` no *ConnectionString*.

Foi o que tentei mas sem resultado.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AssociGestorDb" 
        connectionString="Server=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
                          Database=AssociGestorDb;
                          Integrated Security=True;
                          Current Language=Portuguese;
                          Connect Timeout=30"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Por outro lado se utilizar SQLExpress já funciona.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AssociGestorDb"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Server=.\SQLExpress;
                           Trusted_Connection=true;
                           Current Language=Portuguese;
                           Database=AssociGestorDb"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Qual é a modo correto para conseguir ter as mensagens de erro em português no (LocalDB)\v11.0?

Answer (score 5):

Não sei como realizar a configuração do servidor, mas quando preciso saber o significado de uma mensagem de erro, executo o seguinte select:

```
select * from master.dbo.sysmessages 
where msglangid = 1046
order by error
```

Onde `msglangid` **1046** faz referencia à mensagem no idioma português, e `error` é o código do erro que o servidor retorna.

Comment: Muito útil buscar as mensagens de erro por código do idioma! Estou tentando escrever uma biblioteca para extrair heuristicamente o máximo de informação dessas mensagens de erros de forma estruturada e comparar as mensagens nos diversos idiomas facilitou muito!